# Borel-Weil like results in positive characteristics

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, representation-theory, lie-groups, algebraic-groups

I am aware of the Borel-Weil Theorem over $\mathbb{C}$ as treated in [https://www3.nd.edu/~snow/Papers/HomogVB.pdf](https://www3.nd.edu/%7Esnow/Papers/HomogVB.pdf), for instance. However, I am interested in similar results in positive characteristic. In particular I want the following to hold.

> 1. Suppose $T$ is a maximal torus contained in $B$ a Borel subgroup of a semisimple algebraic group $G$. Then every line bundle $L\in \operatorname{Pic} G/B$ can be ``obtained" from a (rational) character of $T$, in the usual way.
> 2. Consider the Weyl Chamber defined by $B$, say $C(B)$. Consider the roots positive with respect to $C(B)$. Suppose $\chi_1, \ldots, \chi_l$ are the simple roots. Then the ample line bundles in $\operatorname{Pic} G/B$ are precisely those obtained from $\sum_{1\le i \le l} c_i\chi_i$ such that each $c_i>0$.

I would be grateful if someone could point me to (English) references for these results.

Thanks.